# count excel rows dynamically using perl

Tags: perl, excel

I am writing a Perl script which parses an Excel file. The aim of this script is to count for each cell value in column 1, the number of values it has in column 2.

Per example an Excel file that looks like this :

```
12    abc
12    abc
12    efg
12    efg
13    hij
13    hij
13    klm
```

My script would return:

For cell value 12 I have :

```
2 values "abc", 2 values "efg" and for cell value 13 i have : 2 values "hij" and 1 value "klm".
```

My script would look something like this (I took this example from the perl doc) :

```
 use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

 my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('Book1.xlsx');

 foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) {

    printf("Sheet: %s\n", $sheet->{Name});

    $sheet -> {MaxRow} ||= $sheet -> {MinRow}; 

     foreach my $row ($sheet -> {MinRow} .. $sheet -> {MaxRow}) {

            $sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};

            foreach my $col ($sheet -> {MinCol} ..  $sheet -> {MaxCol}) {

                    my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col];

                    if ($cell) {
                        #here I should count the cell values 
                    }
                print $cell;
            }

    }


 }
```

I have no idea how to do this since I've never used perl before in my life, and I can't find examples online that match what I want exactly. Any help would be much much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind: why Perl and not VBA?

Comment: Honestly, it was not my choice. This is part of my internship project within the company.

Comment: @Brad: Because simple things should be simple?

Comment: @runrig It's simple if you know Perl and it's simple if you know VBA. Except can perl scripts be saved/embedded with the Excel file?

Comment: @Brad: Will VBA parse an Excel document where Excel is not installed?

Comment: probably not without it being a huge headache. If that's your situation then you're probably taking a sensible route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following commented script will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use Data::Dumper;

# No need to iterate through columns, so set val for col 1
my $col1 = 0;
my %hash;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new('Book1.xlsx');

# Just get the first sheet
my $sheet = ${ $excel->{Worksheet} }[0];

# Calculate the range of rows
$sheet->{MaxRow} ||= $sheet->{MinRow};

# Iterate through each row
foreach my $row ( $sheet->{MinRow} .. $sheet->{MaxRow} ) {

    # The cell in column 1
    my $cell = $sheet->{Cells}[$row][$col1];

    if ($cell) {

        # The adjacent cell in column 2
        my $adjacentCell = $sheet->{Cells}[$row][ $col1 + 1 ];

        # Use a hash of hashes
        $hash{ $cell->{Val} }{ $adjacentCell->{Val} }++;
    }
}

# Numerically sort the keys; the value is a hash reference
for my $key1 ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
    print "For cell value $key1: ";

    # Dereference the hash reference and get the keys/values
    while ( my ( $key2, $val2 ) = each %{ $hash{$key1} } ) {
        print qq{$val2 value(s) "$key2" };
    }
    print "\n";
}

# Show the hash structure
print "\n", Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
For cell value 12: 2 value(s) "abc" 2 value(s) "efg" 
For cell value 13: 1 value(s) "klm" 2 value(s) "hij" 

$VAR1 = {
          '13' => {
                    'klm' => 1,
                    'hij' => 2
                  },
          '12' => {
                    'abc' => 2,
                    'efg' => 2
                  }
        };
```

You can do the following to show the values associated with key '13':

```
# Show only the value(s) for key '13'
print "For cell value 13: ";

# Dereference the hash reference for key '13' and get the keys/values
while ( my ( $key2, $val2 ) = each %{ $hash{13} } ) {
    print qq{$val2 value(s) "$key2" };
}
```

Output:

```
For cell value 13: 1 value(s) "klm" 2 value(s) "hij"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I need to spend more time working on perl that's for sure! Just a question please, can I access cell values with this hash? I just want to count for cell "13", klm + hij. Is this possible? Thank you :)

Comment: @user1734229 - Am glad this worked for you.  Have added code to show the values associated with key '13'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash. Count with `$hash{$column1}{$column2}++`. Iterate over the keys and print the counted values. Yes, I left you some work to do filling in the values of column1, column2, and iterating over the hash.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so I don't need to iterate through $col and $row anymore? How can I print the hash, print $hash gives me HASH(0x349adc).